# How can I implement a view such that it increase like a rounded circle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a task in which I have to increase the view size depending on timer value. I know view frame will be increased, however I am searching the way like the first round completed then another layer round comes on it so that the view frame size increased and the desired output will also shows.
[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you talking about rounds like rounds in a game, or round as in round circles? Do you want the circles to smoothly grow in size, or do you want to add new, larger circles each time your timer fires?

Comment: As per your image, I understand that on first time small circle and then new circle creates on it as time increases....right..?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is Code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{
    var offsetx:CGFloat!
    var offsety:CGFloat!
    var size: CGFloat!
    var timer: Timer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        offsetx = view.frame.size.width/2.0;
        offsety = view.frame.size.height/2.0;
        size = 1.0
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.7, target: self, selector: #selector(drawCircle), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func drawCircle() {
        let cirecle:UIView = UIView()
        cirecle.frame = CGRect(x: offsetx, y: offsety, width: size, height: size);
        cirecle.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        cirecle.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        cirecle.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cirecle.layer.cornerRadius = size / 2.0
        offsetx = offsetx - 6.0
        offsety = offsety - 6.0
        size = size + 12.0
        view.addSubview(cirecle)

    }
```

Comment: If any issue with code then tell me.

Comment: Sure I will reply you....

Comment: Thanks....your approach works for me....

Answer (score -1):

Something like this...

```
var radius = 1
func drawCircle() {
    let circle = UIView()
    circle.frame.size = CGSize(width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2)
    circle.backgroundColor =  .clear
    circle.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    circle.layer.borderWidth = 1
    circle.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    circle.center = self.center
    view.addSubview(circle)
    radius += 1
}
```

Note. Not sure if you wanna keep adding views. If not, put the view property outside the method and only update the size and / or remove it first from the superview before you initialize it again. Moreover you probably wanna limit the radius to a maximum value.